# exc_bad_access error//

Tags: objective-c

I'm using Xcode 4 and ARC, and I'm getting this error when I'm trying to do this exercise in the book. The `Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".` is at the line with `Rectangle *intersectingRect = [[Rectangle alloc] init];` in the `intersect` method in the `Rectangle.m`.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYPoint : NSObject 
@property float x, y;

@end
```

---

```
#import "XYPoint.h"

@implementation XYPoint 
@synthesize x, y;

@end
```

---

```
#import "XYPoint.h"

@interface Rectangle : NSObject  
@property float width, height;

-(void) setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt;
-(XYPoint *) origin;
-(BOOL) containsPoint: (XYPoint *) aPoint;
-(Rectangle *) intersect: (Rectangle *) myRect;

@end
```

---

```
#import "Rectangle.h"

@implementation Rectangle {
    XYPoint *origin;
}
@synthesize width, height;

-(void) setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt {
    if (! origin) 
        origin = [[XYPoint alloc] init];

    origin.x = pt.x;
    origin.y = pt.y;

}

-(XYPoint *) origin {
    XYPoint *myOrigin = [[XYPoint alloc] init];

    myOrigin.x = origin.x;
    myOrigin.y = origin.y;

    return myOrigin;
}

-(BOOL) containsPoint:(XYPoint *)aPoint {
    if (origin.x + height >= aPoint.x && origin.y + width >= aPoint.y)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}

-(Rectangle *) intersect:(Rectangle *)myRect {
    Rectangle *intersectingRect = [[Rectangle alloc] init];


    if ([self intersect: myRect]){
        intersectingRect.width = self.origin.x + self.width - myRect.origin.x;
        intersectingRect.height = myRect.origin.y + myRect.height - self.origin.y;

        intersectingRect.origin.x = myRect.origin.x;
        intersectingRect.origin.y = self.origin.y;
    }
    return intersectingRect;
}
```

Comment: Wont the `[self intersect: myRect]` call cause an infinite recursion? (your calling the function itself with the same argument as it was called with).

Comment: First thing first, you need to understand why EXC_BAD_ACCESS is thrown. Usually because you are trying to access something that has already been released. You could see it as maybe intersectingRect being the one giving you the problem, but it very well may be myRect that has already been released. How are you retaining myRect?

Comment: Oh oops I used the wrong method. I was suppose to call the containsPoint method. Fixing that solved the error. Thank you!